# New Category-Not appearing in Nav bar

Tags: navigation

I have followed all the steps in creating a new category. I made the sub-cat, rewrote the URL. But when I save and reload my website the new tab doesn't appear.

Do I need to do something else in order for it to appear in the nav bar?

Comment: Is it on M1 or M2 ? Have you associated a product to your new sub-category?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clear the browser history/cash? I would also recommend to clear magento cash after changing some tasks, like translations, attributes, categories etc.

Comment: Basically the new tab if for our catalog. When the customer clicks the tab. It should bring them to the catalog page. I have a catalog Page created. I just want to add a tab that links to that page. It’s magento 1